# The easiest way to collect data with dynamic questions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My target is to make a spreadsheet collect data from users. There are 1000 similar questions:
i.e. do you like product A?  Do you like product B?  etc...
With google form, I can create one but I cannot dynamically change the questions. I want to select 5 questions out of 1000 and show them to different users.
Can anyone help? How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to use Google Forms to input user data in a Google Sheet. I'd make a new spreadsheet with one sheet to serve as your question database, then another sheet (or more) to hold the responses. Using the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), you can easily pick random questions from this spreadsheet and insert responses in it too. Finally, using the [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/), you can make your own form that pulls questions and pushes responses through the server-side stuff via [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if my data is a question with an image? Can I still use one sheet as database?

Comment: I would upload all the images you have to Google drive (or any other image hosting service, really) and just keep URL's to each of them in your spreadsheet "database." Then, you'll just insert the image in your form with a simple img tag, just like any other website.